# Reference for a theorem related to second Cousin problem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, several-complex-variables, sheaf-cohomology

I need a reference for the following theorem:

> Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain of holomorphy. Let $\mathcal{O}^*$ be the sheaf of germs of invertible holomorphic functions on $\Omega$. Then 
>   $$\check{\mathrm{H}}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{O}^*)=0\iff\check{\mathrm{H}}^2(\Omega,\mathbb{Z})=0.$$

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't this just follow from the exponential sequence on $\Omega$ and Cartan's Theorem B?

Comment: Might as well turns this into a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential sequence for $\Omega$ gives an exact sequence
\begin{align*}
\cdots \check H^1(\Omega, {\cal O}) \to \check H^1(\Omega, {\cal O}^*) \to \check H^2(\Omega, \mathbb{Z}) \to \check H^2(\Omega, {\cal O}) \to \cdots
\end{align*}
But ${\cal O}$ is coherent over $\Omega$ and thus acyclic by Cartan's Theorem B.